# CSV Import Bugs - Date/Time Involved

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Dates,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
#2010-01-03 15:01:00#,1.1648,1.1648,1.1622,1.1646,8
#2010-01-03 15:02:00#,1.1648,1.1648,1.1648,1.1648,1
#2010-01-03 15:03:00#,1.1648,1.1648,1.1648,1.1648,2
```

Edit: To be clear, that's `YYYY-MM-DD`.

When I import it into Access 2010 with the following script (it's in `D:\Data\Processed`):

```
Dim strFolderPath As String
strFolderPath = "D:\Data\Processed\"
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir(strFolderPath & "*.txt")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    'MsgBox (objF1.Name)
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , StrFile & "draft", strFolderPath & StrFile, True
    'DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, strFolderPath & objF1.Name, False
    'DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TextImportSpecs", "tblImportedFiles", strFolderPath & objF1.Name, False
    'DoCmd.TransferText _
    'TransferType:=intImportType, _
    'SpecificationName:=strSpecification, _
    'TableName:=strTable, _
    'FileName:=strPath & strFile, _
    'HasFieldNames:=blnHasFieldNames
    'strFile = Dir
    Name strFolderPath & StrFile As "D:\Data\Done\" & StrFile 'Move the files to the archive folder
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
```

It imports the first field as a string, rather than a date. I'd appreciate either changes to the format of the text file (preferred) or changes to the script to accomodate for importing as a date/time object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the pound characters ('#' - is that what you would call them?) from your data file.

I think you know that when tables are created by importing CSV data via the `DoCmd.TransferText` method, Access (Jet) assigns column data types based on the data it finds in a scan of the first rows of the imported data.  If a column has numeric data, Jet assigns that column the `Number` data type, date-formatted data get `DateTime` columns, etc.

In your case Jet could not determine the data type of your 'Dates' column because of the '#' characters and so assigned that column the (rather generic) `Text` data type.

Comment: I'll try that and report back ASAP.